# Direct Path for Desktop without Usernames for Blender 2.79

Tags: python

thanks for the help on my last question.

Now, i want to export to the desktop path of users, without knowing the username.

I try to explain

## Export on Desktop

```
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/users/luki-krew/desktop/"
```

Is working for me, the file get saved as 0001.svg on desktop.

But i want something like:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "~/Desktop/0001.svg"
```

Perfect would be if the file name could be the same like the imported 3d Model. WOULD BE PERFECT !

Like the files named car.fbx - the export should be named car.svg

Than you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below retrieves the home directory and generates the path to the desktop. If the project has been saved before, it adds the name as prefix.

```
import bpy
import os 
from pathlib import Path
from sys import platform

home_dir = str(Path.home())

if platform == 'linux' or platform == 'win32' or platform == 'darwin':
    desktop_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, 'Desktop')
else:
    raise RuntimeError("OS not supported")

if bpy.data.is_saved:
    filename = os.path.splitext(bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath))[0]
    output = os.path.join(desktop_dir, filename)
else:
    # Project file hasn't been saved before, therefore no filename is available
    output = desktop_dir

bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output
```

---

If you want the prefix to be the same as the active object in the scene:

```
import bpy
import os 
from pathlib import Path
from sys import platform

home_dir = str(Path.home())

if platform == 'linux' or platform == 'win32' or platform == 'darwin':
    desktop_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, 'Desktop')
else:
    raise RuntimeError("OS not supported")

if bpy.app.version < (2, 80, 0):
    filename_prefix = bpy.context.scene.objects.active.name
else:
    filename_prefix = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.name

output = os.path.join(desktop_dir, filename_prefix)
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output
```

Comment: Thank you! is it also possible to use the name of the object and not the name of the blend file for output name? :)

Comment: Sure. In Blender 2.79 the currently active object is `bpy.context.scene.objects.active` and in 2.80 `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active`. Assign that to filename and it will use that as prefix. Although then you can also remove the whole `bpy.data.is_saved` check.

Comment: Where i have to insert that code in the code above :D?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: WORKS like a charm but it sets at the end a 0001, dont know why :D Do you know this solution as well :)?

Comment: You need to specify the whole path including the file extension and uncheck *File Extensions* if you don't want the frame number added.